# Huge amount of unmanaged memory in IIS Application Pool. Is it normal?

Tags: iis, memory-management, profiling, overhead

We are trying to find out why our applications hosted in IIS are using up all the RAM on our VMs, and to do that I downloaded some memory profiling tools to experiment with. I first tried JetBrains' dotMemory, but quickly noticed that most of the memory in the application pool process was unmanaged and that dotMemory wasn't being very useful because it deals mostly with managed memory analysis.

[image]

Notice that the pool is using 221MB total, but only 19MB is managed .Net memory.

After toying around with dotMemory, I decided to try out another tool, and found out about ANTS Memory Profiler from RedGate.

[image]

ANTS injects something in the application that does consume a lot of that memory it seems, but it still shows some absurd amounts of physical ram being used:

[image]

Is this acceptable for a very simple WebAPI project? We started noticing that our VM was hitting 95% to 100% memory usage with a few hosted projects, and this was causing the machine to be very slow. We've tried unifying all 4 applications in the same application pool, but this just yielded pretty much the same results: the total memory usage of the single pool was matching that of all 4 separated ones.

You can see from the graphs that the CLR alone seems to be eating up to 80MB of memory. How can we lower the memory usage of IIS application pools? I've read that [changing the pools to x86 mode does reduce a lot of the memory overhead](http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/bugs-issues-/app-pool-memory-drastically-different-from-32-64-bit) and tried it for a few minutes, resulting in some good reduction to almost half the total ram, but even if I go that way I'd like to know why such simple projects are eating so much RAM on IIS.

We are using one of the more basic Azure VMs with only 1.7GB of RAM, and running these 4 very simple web applications (two MVC websites and two WebAPI projects) is already running the VM to the ground.

For some strange reason, on our local development computers the pools seem to use fewer amounts of RAM too. Also, there doesn't seem to be any memory leaks at all, since taking snapshots at random points always yields the same very high but constant memory usage. We are very careful on the code to always dispose disposable objects and we're using the most severe settings for FxCop with zero problems.

Comment: In two words - yes, it's acceptable. .NET GC can allocate as much memory as it need.
"...and this was causing the machine to be very slow" - how did you determined that high memory usage by IIS leads it? Was it memory swapping? Or garbage collecting took a lot of time?
High memory usage by itself does not cause machine slowing. First of all find what caused it accurately.

Comment: @julealgon We're having this EXACT problem. How did you fix this? I also tried those two products, and I also got those results. I keep hitting the IIS memory limit, and my app pool gets recycled. The app itself takes very little memory, but the unmanaged stuff consumes all the "Private Bytes" available!

Comment: @julealgon I'm wondering whether this is due to third party libraries (though most we use are managed anyhow).

Comment: @hbob We didn't fix it. I still have no idea why it uses so much memory. For now, we changed all our pools to 32 bit mode and saw very decent results. I'm still not happy with that solution because it should just work by default. Our applications are extremely simple at the moment. If you don't need to handle 4GB of ram at once, I'd strongly suggest changing all pools to use the x86 w3wp process. After I posted this question, I found [another source](http://www.iis.net/learn/web-hosting/web-server-for-shared-hosting/32-bit-mode-worker-processes) recommending the use of 32bit processes.

Comment: @hbob As for you comment about 3rd party libraries, I think so, yes. Even if we only ever use .Net dlls from NuGet, they could be calling whatever system functions via P/Invoke or using .Net classes that allocate unmanaged memory (like the `Bitmap` class for instance) indirectly. I still intend to start bottom up by adding references and trying to find exactly what is causing the jump in native memory, but this would take ages, time that I really don't have right now.

Comment: @julealgon Wow I just switched to 32bit and my unmanaged memory was slashed by more than half! **Incredible.** LOH and all gens have huge fragmentation now, but you can compact them if you're using .NET 4.5.1 or above.

Comment: @julealgon To compact the LOH, [see here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mariohewardt/archive/2013/06/26/no-more-memory-fragmentation-on-the-large-object-heap.aspx).

Comment: @julealgon I have the same issue, the last note in your question is spot on. Did you find out more about this since? Thanks.

Comment: Not really @TomPažourek. I ended up leaving the company where we were having these issues and this did not come up on newer projects (I'm not into the devops part of it as I was in the other company).

Comment: I also saw interesting results when using a single app pool for multiple web apps. The memory usage of a single app pool is much less than when using separate app pool for each app. It's not a viable solution (less security, less isolation, less control over the apps), but it might be useful to someone, or as a lead when finding a better solution.